# Change/set date in Freemarker

Tags: date, freemarker

I have to use two dates to get some data (somenumbers): `start_date` and `end_date`.

The `end_date` should be now but I want the `start_date` to be the 1st of the current month, which means the `start_date`'s date should always be 1st. Is it possible to do something like:

```
<#assign end_date = .now>
<#assign start_date = .now?replace('dd', 01)>
```

replace(,) can be used but for only strings or only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if absolutely necessary, I'd do it somehow like:

```
<#assign end_date = .now?date >
<#assign now_string = .now?date?iso_local >
<#assign start_string = now_string[0..7] + "01" >
<#assign start_date = start_string?date.iso >
```

(The code can be shortened, I made it a bit "talkative" for better understanding of my intention.)

Anyway, such things **do not** belong to View, they should be done in your Controller.

Comment: Hi Jozef! i still don't get what i was looking for. Could you pls take a look at the answer you've provided and help me with the correct answer pls?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
<#assign today = .now?date?iso("Europe/Zurich")/>
<#assign monthStart = today[0..7] + "01" />
```

Comment: Well, that's basically my solution, only a bit compressed and using a specific timezone. And `monthStart` is of string type, not date.